# In Salesforce development environment, how do I see the logs generated by my controller class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console, developer-productivity

I have a visualforce page and a custom controller. I view the page with the

Url:

```
https://***Salesforce_instance***/apex/myNewPageName?id=some_lead_d
```

Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="MyExtension">
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
     System.debug('Hello world');
    }
}
```

The page shows up correctly but I am not sure where to find the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using Debug logs page in Setup

   - Go to Setup(Click on your name at upper right, click Setup)
   - In the Setup page, type 'Debug' in upper left quick find box
   - Click on 'Debug Logs' link
   - If you already have a log entry, you will see all the debug logs.
   - If you don't have one, create new by giving required values and reload the page to get the debug log.
2. Using developer console

   - Click your name at upper right and click 'Developer Console'
   - In the developer console, expand the bottom panel and select 'Logs' tab.
   - Double click on the log you need to open.
   - If you need to clear the logs from console, Click *Debug > Clear > Log Panel* from the top menu.